# Semantic matching of two sentences

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to measure how much  two sentences are similar in meaning.

```
eg :
    sentence 1 :"my name is jack"
    sentence 2 :'jack is my name"


similarity measure: 99 %
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Read up on ```tfi-df``` (term frequency-inverse document frequency) and cosine similarity. They are the quickest way to get a similar functionality you require.

Comment: what have you tried and what have you done? Do you have any code to share? Semantic matching is no trivial task as it relies on deep knowledge and understanding of the language in which you are processing.

Comment: I have tried cosine similarity but I am looking for matching their meaning and not cosine distance between  word vectors